# Change raster values within a %>% pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, raster, magrittr

I have a raster where the data I am interested in (a species presence) value is 1, and the rest is either 0 (absence) or NA.
I am trying to use magrittr and dplyr and, inside a pipe, I would like to change all 0 values to NA, so I can later trim the raster and get the min and max coordinates of the data where the species is (value = 1)

However, changing value 0 to NA is something I would normally do with something like:

```
raster[values(raster) == 0] <- NA
```

I have trouble doing that kind of operations, "from right to left", with magrittr (can they be done?). I learnt that `names() <-` could be exchanched by `setNames()`, or that you could use the `` symbols to use operation signs (i.e.: `raster %>%`*`(raster2)` to multiply by another raster)`

Is there a way to get an equivalent result working with the pipes?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Just create a function `zero_to_na<-function(x) {x[values(x) == 0] <- NA; x}` and use that in your pipe: `raster %>% zero_to_na`. R is a functional language after all. Don't be afraid to write a function that makes the intention more clear.

Comment: Great, thats a nice way to do it! Thanks a lot @MrFlick, it totally works.
However, I keep wondering if there is a way which is already implemented to do so... I don't know if I am missing something or there are somethings that are just not easy to translate for pipes... (like all those right to left operations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use `raster::reclassify`:

```
library(raster)
library(magrittr)
r <- raster(matrix(0:3, 2))

r %>% reclassify(c(0, 0, NA), right=NA)
```

This may also be ever so slightly faster than @MrFlick's nice `zero_to_na` suggestion (on bigger rasters, anyway!), in case you're doing a lot of this stuff. The tradeoff is that it's clearly less elegant.

```
r <- raster(matrix(rbinom(1e6, 1, 0.5), 1e3))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    this=r %>% reclassify(c(0, 0, NA), right=NA),
    that=r %>% zero_to_na)

Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 this 21.77720 22.85843 32.48079 25.05024 26.05527 168.1101   100  a 
 that 29.46083 31.37556 56.32881 33.48350 38.05476 202.8740   100   b
```

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for. Actually, I was trying with subs, but for some reason I didn't manage to set it up. It is elegant enough for me! Thanks!